# Can I undo a community wiki answer?

Tags: support

Sorry, this is silly, but I would like to check if [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69031) from 2010 is still valid: there is no way to undo a *community wiki* post?

I made a "mistake" tagging all my answers like community wiki, not knowing about the lack of rep. It's no big deal, of course, but I'd like to undo it if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators can remove CW status from a post. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83373/254250):

> Yes—community moderators, at their discretion, can now remove community wiki status from particular posts.

If you want to remove CW status from a post, please flag it for moderator attention, select "other," and explain that you want to remove CW status from the post.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it.